# Building a thesaurus from corpus

Tags: nlp, corpus, thesaurus

I am working on a natural language processing application. I have a text describing 30 domains. Each domain is defined with a short paragraph that explains it. My aim is to build a *thesaurus* from this text so I can determine from an input `string` which domains are concerned. The text is about 5000 words and each domains is described by 150 words.  My questions are :

Do I have a long enough text to create a thesaurus from ?

Is my idea of building a thesaurus legit or should I just use NLP libraries to analyse my corpus and the input string ?

At the moment, I have calculated the number total of occurrence of each words grouped by domains because I first thought of a indexed approach. But I am really not sure which method is the best. Does someone have experience in both NLP and thesaurus building ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is topic modeling. Given a word, you want to get the probability of which domain the word belongs to. I would recommend using off the shelf algorithms that implement LDA (Latent Dirichlet Algorithm). 
Alternatively, you can visit [David Blei's website](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html). He has written some great software that implements LDA, and topic modeling in general. He also has presented several tutorials for topic modeling for beginners.

Comment: It seems to be what I was looking for. I also heard about HMM (Markov) algorithm which is pretty relevant. I'll study the two of them and see how a should use them. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to build a thesaurus then build a thesaurus; if your goal is not to build a thesaurus, then you better use stuff available out there.

More generally, for any task in NLP - from data acquisition to machine translation - you're gonna face numerous problems (both technical and theoretical), and it is very easy to stray from the path, as these problems are - most of the time - fascinating.

Whatever the task is, build a system using existing resources. Then you get the big picture; then you can start thinking about improving component A or B.

Good luck.

Comment: My goal isn't to build or not to build a thesaurus, it is to understand what my application's users are writing to conclude which domains they are talking about. If it involves building a thesaurus, I'll build it. But does it ? 
And what do you mean by "build a system using existing resources" ? Which resources are you thinking of ? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a lot of resources available out there (lexicons, tokenizer, stemmer, parser, named entity recognizer, etc.), you should be able to build your system just by combining them. As for a thesaurus, you might want to start with Wordnet (which is free).

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll do everything I can with what exists.